# Parameterized test with dynamic class creation possible?

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized

We have a lot of custom unchecked exceptions which have 3 overloaded constructors (one each with message, cause and both message and cause) taking in different parameters. We essentially write the same test for each and every such class. I was wondering if it would be possible to create a common utility to which we could just supply the class type of the custom exception and it runs through the test cases creating instances on the fly for those custom class types. Is this possible?

I'm struggling with the instantiation piece. Do I need to use reflection? Is there a better way to handle this? Here is what I have:

```
 @RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
public class ParameterizedTest
{
    // Is this even needed?
    private final Throwable throwable;

    public ParameterizedTest(Throwable throwable)
    {
        this.throwable = throwable;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> data()
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { {ExportException, ImportException}});
    }

     @Test
        public void testConstructor_withMessage()
        {
            String message = "message";
            // I want the object constructed to be of the type supplied in the parameters above
            Throwable exception = new Throwable(message);
            assertSame(message, exception.getMessage());
            assertNull(exception.getCause());
        }

         @Test
public void testConstructor_withMessageAndCause()
{
    Throwable cause = new Throwable();
    String message = "message";
    Throwable exception = new Throwable(message, cause);
    assertSame(message, exception.getMessage());
    assertSame(cause, exception.getCause());
}
```

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Java 8?

Comment: We're on Java 7